# Scala Generic inference

Tags: scala, generics

I desire to have automatic type inference on a class with a sequence `s` of objects which are descendant of `A`, knowing that `A` takes generic parameters.

```
class A[F](val field1: F)

class G[F, Aa <: A[F], S <: Seq[Aa]](val s: S) {
  // what i have to do
}

// Evrything is ok
val gWith = new G[Int, A[Int], List[A[Int]]](List(new A(5)))

// Compilator failed: inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,List[A[Int]]]
val gWithout = new G(List(new A(5)))
```

I will add that i explicitly need to know `Aa` and `S` types to reuse them later.

Is there any solution to dispense user to put these generic types. If not i will be happy to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the type parameters for your `G` class:

```
class A[F](val field1: F)

class B[F](override val field1: F) extends A[F](field1)

// Make A covariant
class G[F, S[+A] <: Seq[A]](val s: S[A[F]]) { }

// Everything is ok
val gWith = new G[Int, List](List(new A(5)))

// Also ok
val gWithout = new G(List(new A(5)))

// Ok too
val gBWithout = new G(List(new B(5)))
```

Working scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fmOLxCiKRBKIDFSj7stZNQ

Comment: I agree with you except if i explicitly need to know the `Aa`  or `S` type what is i'm constraint to.

Comment: @KyBe See updated answer and scastie.  Does that better fit what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with a type constraints

```
class A[F](val field1: F)

class G[F, Aa, S](val s: S)(implicit ev2: S <:< Seq[Aa], ev1: Aa <:< A[F]) {}

val gWithout = new G(List(new A(5))) // gWithout: G[Int,A[Int],List[A[Int]]] = G@79d7035
```

I can't really explain why it doesn't work before and why it works now, but I can tell you it is related to type inference, I have been playing in the RELP with your snippet for a while *(using the '-explaintypes' flag)* and I always found some strange errors like:

> Nothing <: List[A[Int]]?
>
> true
>
> Nothing <: Any?
>
> true
>
> Nothing <: A[Nothing]?
>
> true
>
> List[A[Int]] <: Seq[Nothing]?
>
> false
>
> error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,List[A[Int]]] do not conform to class G's type parameter bounds [F,Aa <: A[F],S <: Seq[Aa]]
>
> val gWithout = new G(List(new A(5)))
>
> List[A[Int]] <: S?
> false

I found [this post](http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html), I haven't read it completely yet, but it seems there is a better explanation of why this now works.